# Why does release include .pdb file?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have thinking that release mode does not have .pdb file . Recently I publish .Net core web app using command line and it includes pdb files. This is bit strange for me.

Comment: PDB files contain symbol information (method names etc) in both release and in debug mode. You should absolutely deploy them so that you can profile your production application and get method names and other critical information.

Comment: My doubt is that when I checked released version of DLL and there is a exception in it. It also display which file throw the exception like HomeController.cs and line no 123 so i think this type information only available in Debug mode.

Comment: It's not. It's available in release mode too.

Answer (score 1):

It is confiugrable in project properties as many other aspects of code building  (optimization level, enabling/disabling conditional compilation switchers etc.).

In many cases PDB brings you additional information which you would not have without it: line numbers in stack trace (in case of unhandled expception error wroted to the log). There is a long tradition to public pdb with release versions on MS dev platform. Actually you should have a strong reason to do not puplish them (I always do).